# I am getting an error when I am launching Appium on Android

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

When launching Appium on Android I get following error:

> Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for
>   more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred
>   while processing the command. Original error: The desired capabilities
>   must include either an app, appPackage or browserName Build info:
>   version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:25:53'

My code:

```
package SignupUchat;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class Signup_Uchat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();

        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "HUAWEI");
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "8.1.0");
        dc.setCapability("appPakage","com.android.calculator2");
        dc.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

        URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver=new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url,dc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your posted is all code, there is no stack trace. Please share the error you getting and add some explanation.

Comment: When i was run that code it will get below Error:

Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The desired capabilities must include either an app, appPackage or browserName
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'

Answer (score 1):

It seem like your wrong at the line:

```
dc.setCapability("appPakage","com.android.calculator2");
```

It should:

```
dc.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.calculator2");
```

`appPackage` not `appPakage`

[Capabilities](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#android-only)

Comment: Now i getting Error :

: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'

Comment: Please make sure the device is connected to the server, and make sure `DEVICE_NAME` `PLATFORM_VERSION` not wrong in your capability.

Comment: Already check device is connected but I get Error Message in Appium :

[ADB] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
[ADB] Restarting adb
[ADB] Killing adb server on port 5037

Comment: Can you share the `adb` log after your check?

Comment: Where i can get adb log?

Comment: As i already said that device is connected so i check through Command prompt through :

C:\Users>adb devices
List of devices attached
YGC6R19304013359        device

Comment: Not sure, but I think you have problem about configuration, make sure your devices connected in the same port with your appium server. Look your server in your question, it say `4723` but the error you getting in your above comment is `5037`, this is not matching

Comment: The point is your devices not connected  in the `http://127.0.0.1:4723`

Comment: Ok i'll cross check then let you know.thanx

Comment: Now I'm getting different Error message :

Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error Command ''C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_181\\bin\\java.exe' -jar

Comment: 'C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-android-driver\\node_modules\\appium-adb\\jars\\sign.jar' 'C:\\Program Files\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' --override' exited with code 1